# How to redirect user from outside app like browser to specific screen inside react native app

Tags: android, ios, react-native, deep-linking, android-universal-link

I'm trying to implement payment in my app and  i need to redirect user from browser to specific screen in my app after payment.
The problem is i'm able to do it with deeplinking
This is the URL schème that i'm using:
my_app_name://payment
And everything is working okay, when testing locally thé deeplink in working fine
however the bank is asking me to provide the return URL as a Universal URL with https because they don't support deeplinking i think
i have to do it like that:
https://my_app_name/payment for example
I thought that my app should be published in store to be able to generate such URL.
I published the app to store, however i'm struggling to generate such URL.
Many ressources are talking about Deeplinks, Universal links and App links.
But i think i don't understand well how Can i do it ?
Can someone please help and explain how should i achieve such behavior in my react native app in both Android and iOS.

I created a deeplink inside my app:
my_app_name:// payment.
Everything is working fine with deeplink when tested but bank does Handle links with https, so i have to change it.